# Image GD resize to 100px while keep the ratio

Tags: php, resize, jpeg, gd

I want to resize an image to 100px (wide, or high), while keeping its ratio and quality.
All this needs to do is open a given file, resize it and overwrite the file with the new version (keeping the filename).
It should only be able to do jpeg, gif and png files.
I'm not fussy about transparencies.

Comment: Haha! This was posted in 2009, the 'dupe' was posted in 2013.