# How to render image quality/size using URL?

Tags: javascript, image-processing, amazon-s3

If you look at websites like Medium, you will notice that the URL of the image controls the quality % and size of the image.

i.e.
https://d262ilb51hltx0.cloudfront.net/max/1280/1*trqJ8rY4_duJtwAOJOJS6w.jpeg
This image is rendered as 1280px wide and max quality.

How can I do the same thing? I host my images on Amazon s3 and I want to be able to do exactly the same thing. How?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Javascript, but server-side question.

If you're using PHP, you can use functions of the [GD library](https://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) to manipulate your images. You can resize images before sending them to the client, choose JPEG quality, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the route parameters to server and use server side tools to process the images. You can use tools like [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org)

If you are using php.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Refer this stackoverflow question [How to scale down an image on the server side with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084751/how-to-scale-down-an-image-on-the-server-side-with-php)

In node there is an npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemagick

```
var im = require('imagemagick');
im.convert(['kittens.jpg', '-resize', '25x120', 'kittens-small.jpg'], 
function(err, stdout){
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('stdout:', stdout);
});
```

Comment: Is there an example of this in Node.JS or Meteor.JS?

Comment: An meteor example to use imagemagick during uploading. https://github.com/ideaq/image-uploads . check the server file https://github.com/ideaq/image-uploads/blob/master/server/server_save_file.js .  He is using meteorhacks:npm package to add npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemagick to meteor. Add `"imagemagick": "0.1.3"` to package.json  An example for resize `im.convert(['kittens.jpg', '-resize', '25x120', 'kittens-small.jpg'], 
function(err, stdout){
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('stdout:', stdout);
});`