# PHP resize image to fit within a certain area

Tags: php, image, resize

I have an image file that is stored within the variable `$image` I want to resize this image so it would fit within an area of **380px by 380px** (so which means that the tallest side of the image must be 380px on the other side smaller than 380px).
Has anyone a suggestion on how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to change the image permanently, or just display it at a particular size?

Comment: Basically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373426/image-gd-resize-to-100px-while-keep-the-ratio

Comment: @BrianWarshaw change it permanently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is what I use to keep it under 800x600

```
$orig_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file['tmp_name']);
list($width,$height) = getimagesize($file['tmp_name']);
if(max($width,$height) > 800){
  $scale = 800/max($width,$height);
  $new_width = floor($width*$scale);
  $new_height = floor($height*$scale);
  $save_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width,$new_height);
  imagecopyresampled($save_image,$orig_image,0,0,0,0,$new_width,$new_height,$width,$height);
  imagejpeg($save_image,self::$FILE_DIRECTORY."$year_month/$fileId.jpg");
  $orig_image = $save_image;
  $width = $new_width;
  $height = $new_height;
}
```

hopefully you can extrapolate a solution off that.. also not that my $file variable is coming from an uploaded file in the $_FILE array.

Comment: also don't worry about the last three variables (i also create thumbnail images and that's what those are for)

Comment: Really handy. Worked perfectly for my use.